# Asterisk segfault error 4 in libsqlite3.so.0.8.6

Tags: asterisk

I use Asterisk 11.3.0 and every 3-4 days im geting this in dmesg :

```
asterisk[24467]: segfault at 18 ip 00007f7e5c49ba3f sp 00007f7e035fb500 error 4 in libsqlite3.so.0.8.6[7f7e5c46b000+8c000]
```

after that asterisk crashes and i need to restart it.

I used gdb to find solution in core file and it shows me this :

```
*#0  __ao2_callback (c=0x0, arg=0x7fbfaf050290, flags=OBJ_POINTER) at astobj2.c:1190
#1  __ao2_find (c=0x0, arg=0x7fbfaf050290, flags=OBJ_POINTER) at astobj2.c:1221
#2  0x00000000004d7f2b in find_interface (format1=<value optimized out>, format2=0x7fbf70935c28) at format.c:107
#3  format_cmp_helper (format1=<value optimized out>, format2=0x7fbf70935c28) at format.c:314
#4  0x00000000004da242 in cmp_cb (obj=<value optimized out>, arg=<value optimized out>, flags=<value optimized out>) at format_cap.c:56
#5  0x0000000000447652 in internal_ao2_callback (c=0x7fbf7124bf58, flags=OBJ_POINTER, cb_fn=<value optimized out>, arg=0x7fbf7124944c, data=0x0, type=DEFAULT, tag=0x0, file=0x0, line=0, 
    func=0x0) at astobj2.c:1085
#6  0x00000000004480aa in __ao2_callback (c=<value optimized out>, arg=<value optimized out>, flags=<value optimized out>) at astobj2.c:1190
#7  __ao2_find (c=<value optimized out>, arg=<value optimized out>, flags=<value optimized out>) at astobj2.c:1221
#8  0x00000000004da166 in ast_format_cap_iscompatible (cap=<value optimized out>, format=<value optimized out>) at format_cap.c:318
#9  0x00007fbfd8b86fd7 in sip_rtp_read (ast=0x7fbf70da2288) at chan_sip.c:8344
#10 sip_read (ast=0x7fbf70da2288) at chan_sip.c:8389
#11 0x0000000000484c78 in __ast_read (chan=0x7fbf70da2288, dropaudio=0) at channel.c:4010
#12 0x00007fbfcbdf6fde in wait_for_answer (qe=0x7fbfaf053320, outgoing=0x7fbf2c540930, to=0x7fbfaf0531d8, digit=0x7fbfaf0531df "", prebusies=<value optimized out>, caller_disconnect=0, 
    forwardsallowed=1) at app_queue.c:4527
#13 0x00007fbfcbdf844a in try_calling (qe=0x7fbfaf053320, opts=..., opt_args=0x7fbfaf054520, announceoverride=<value optimized out>, url=0x7fbfaf0532a8 "", tries=<value optimized out>, 
    noption=0x7fbf2ca7d3e0, agi=0x7fbf71249448 "\002", macro=0x7fc01526fbd0 "AWAVAUE1\355ATUH\211\375S\211\313H\203\354(\350\035\324\377\377\003\230p\002", 
    gosub=0x7fc0199a6619 "H\211\320H\203\304\bH=\001\360\377\377s\001\303H\213\rp\031+", ringing=0) at app_queue.c:5379
#14 0x00007fbfcbdfc53b in queue_exec (chan=0x7fbf70da2288, data=<value optimized out>) at app_queue.c:7108
#15 0x000000000051bca4 in pbx_exec (c=0x7fbf70da2288, app=0x2921650, data=0x7fbfaf056680 "stp,tTc,,,1500") at pbx.c:1589
#16 0x0000000000526434 in pbx_extension_helper (c=0x7fbf70da2288, con=0x0, context=<value optimized out>, exten=<value optimized out>, priority=6, label=0x0, 
    callerid=0x7fbf71499690 "4959479643", action=E_SPAWN, found=0x7fbfaf058cfc, combined_find_spawn=1) at pbx.c:4665
#17 0x000000000052d3f5 in ast_spawn_extension (c=0x7fbf70da2288, args=0x0) at pbx.c:5781
#18 __ast_pbx_run (c=0x7fbf70da2288, args=0x0) at pbx.c:6256
#19 0x000000000052eb7b in pbx_thread (data=<value optimized out>) at pbx.c:6586
#20 0x000000000056ec5b in dummy_start (data=<value optimized out>) at utils.c:1091
#21 0x00007fc0183ea851 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#22 0x00007fc0199b390d in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6*
```

thread apply all bt show this :

```
Thread 153 (Thread 0x7fd27e25d700 (LWP 23043)):
0  0x00007fd2f360a253 in poll () from /lib64/libc.so.6
1  0x00000000004820d1 in ast_waitfor_nandfds (c=0x7fd27e2571b8, n=1, fds=0x30b4e, nfds=1417518661, exception=0x0, outfd=0x7fd27e2571e4, ms=0x2e6c656e6e616863) at channel.c:3254
2  0x00000000004860a2 in ast_waitfordigit_full (c=0x7fd25491aea8, timeout_ms=1000, cmdfd=-1, audiofd=-1) at channel.c:3622
3  0x00007fd2a5a47415 in wait_our_turn (chan=0x7fd25491aea8, data=<value optimized out>) at app_queue.c:4755
4  queue_exec (chan=0x7fd25491aea8, data=<value optimized out>) at app_queue.c:7055
5  0x000000000051bca4 in pbx_exec (c=0x7fd25491aea8, app=0x361d720, data=0x7fd27e25a680 "ao,tTc,,,1200") at pbx.c:1589
6  0x0000000000526434 in pbx_extension_helper (c=0x7fd25491aea8, con=0x0, context=<value optimized out>, exten=<value optimized out>, priority=19, label=0x0, 
    callerid=0x7fd25404ad50 "9166506959", action=E_SPAWN, found=0x7fd27e25ccfc, combined_find_spawn=1) at pbx.c:4665
7  0x000000000052d3f5 in ast_spawn_extension (c=0x7fd25491aea8, args=0x0) at pbx.c:5781
8  __ast_pbx_run (c=0x7fd25491aea8, args=0x0) at pbx.c:6256
9  0x000000000052eb7b in pbx_thread (data=<value optimized out>) at pbx.c:6586
10 0x000000000056ec5b in dummy_start (data=<value optimized out>) at utils.c:1091
11 0x00007fd2f204a851 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
12 0x00007fd2f361390d in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6

Thread 152 (Thread 0x7fd27d2dd700 (LWP 23075)):
0  0x00007fd2f204e7bb in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
1  0x0000000000448be0 in ast_audiohook_trigger_wait (audiohook=0x7fd1d80ddb10) at audiohook.c:939
2  0x00007fd2b46b8388 in mixmonitor_thread (obj=0x7fd1d80ddb10) at app_mixmonitor.c:635
3  0x000000000056ec5b in dummy_start (data=<value optimized out>) at utils.c:1091
4  0x00007fd2f204a851 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
5  0x00007fd2f361390d in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6

Thread 151 (Thread 0x7fd27d3d5700 (LWP 24008)):
0  0x00007fd2f2051054 in __lll_lock_wait () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
1  0x00007fd2f204c3a3 in _L_lock_892 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
2  0x00007fd2f204c287 in pthread_mutex_lock () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
3  0x0000000000447b5d in internal_ao2_callback (c=0x213ec18, flags=OBJ_NODATA, cb_fn=<value optimized out>, arg=0x7fd27d3d42c0, data=0x0, type=DEFAULT, tag=0x0, file=0x0, line=0, func=0x0)
    at astobj2.c:1071
4  0x0000000000447d21 in __ao2_callback (c=<value optimized out>, flags=<value optimized out>, cb_fn=<value optimized out>, arg=<value optimized out>) at astobj2.c:1190
5  0x00007fd2b27c7cf1 in sip_show_channels (e=<value optimized out>, cmd=<value optimized out>, a=<value optimized out>) at chan_sip.c:20737
6  0x00000000004938c7 in ast_cli_command_full (uid=0, gid=0, fd=551, s=0x7fd27d3d4650 "sip show channels") at cli.c:2560
7  0x0000000000493afc in ast_cli_command_multiple_full (uid=0, gid=0, fd=551, size=18, s=0x7fd27d3d4abf "sip show channels") at cli.c:2583
8  0x0000000000440259 in netconsole (vconsole=0x8401f8) at asterisk.c:1336
9  0x000000000056ec5b in dummy_start (data=<value optimized out>) at utils.c:1091
10 0x00007fd2f204a851 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
11 0x00007fd2f361390d in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6

Thread 150 (Thread 0x7fd29d486700 (LWP 13766)):
0  0x00007fd2f360a253 in poll () from /lib64/libc.so.6
1  0x00000000004820d1 in ast_waitfor_nandfds (c=0x7fd29d47de00, n=2, fds=0x0, nfds=0, exception=0x0, outfd=0x0, ms=0x2e6c656e6e616863) at channel.c:3254
2  0x0000000000489428 in ast_waitfor_n (c0=0x7fd25435cdd8, c1=0x7fd1d847d498, config=0x7fd29d480060, fo=0x7fd29d47e298, rc=0x7fd29d47e290) at channel.c:3535
3  ast_generic_bridge (c0=0x7fd25435cdd8, c1=0x7fd1d847d498, config=0x7fd29d480060, fo=0x7fd29d47e298, rc=0x7fd29d47e290) at channel.c:7540
4  ast_channel_bridge (c0=0x7fd25435cdd8, c1=0x7fd1d847d498, config=0x7fd29d480060, fo=0x7fd29d47e298, rc=0x7fd29d47e290) at channel.c:8018
5  0x00000000004c3466 in ast_bridge_call (chan=0x7fd25435cdd8, peer=0x7fd1d847d498, config=0x7fd29d480060) at features.c:4464
6  0x00007fd2a5a44ddb in try_calling (qe=0x7fd29d480320, opts=..., opt_args=0x7fd29d481520, announceoverride=<value optimized out>, url=0x0, tries=<value optimized out>, 
    noption=0x2e6c656e6e616863, agi=<value optimized out>, macro=<value optimized out>, gosub=<value optimized out>, ringing=1702125924) at app_queue.c:5874
7  0x00007fd2a5a4753b in queue_exec (chan=0x7fd25435cdd8, data=<value optimized out>) at app_queue.c:7108
8  0x000000000051bca4 in pbx_exec (c=0x7fd25435cdd8, app=0x361d720, data=0x7fd29d483680 "stp,tTc") at pbx.c:1589
9  0x0000000000526434 in pbx_extension_helper (c=0x7fd25435cdd8, con=0x0, context=<value optimized out>, exten=<value optimized out>, priority=7, label=0x0,
```

Can you guys help me to solve this problem ?

Will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

current asterisk 11.x version is 11.14.You are using very old version and ask someone debug it? please change to current asterisk and libsqlite version, update your glibc,other system lib after that check if issue exist. 99% chance you will never spot it after that.